# C++ hello world not working?

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc

I am new to C++ and I am self-teaching. I am using `code::blocks`, and have a question.  When I write hello world, nothing happens. This is what is says in the debugger window:

```
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
ERROR: You need to specify a debugger program in the debuggers's settings.
(For MinGW compilers, it's 'gdb.exe' (without the quotes))
(For MSVC compilers, it's 'cdb.exe' (without the quotes))
```

and here is the program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Helloworld!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

also if you need it, here is the build log:

```
"hello world again - Debug": The compiler's setup (GNU GCC Compiler) is invalid, so Code::Blocks cannot find/run the compiler.
Probably the toolchain path within the compiler options is not setup correctly?!
Goto "Settings->Compiler and debugger...->Global compiler settings->GNU GCC Compiler->Toolchain executables" and fix the compiler's setup.
Skipping...
Nothing to be done (all items are up-to-date).
```

Comment: What's in the global compiler settings? Is there a debugger filled in?

Comment: Your program probably works fine if you run it without the debugger.

Answer (score 6):

Try to download the debugger and the compiler again. It worked for me when I had this problem. Try downloading the 'gdb.exe' from the internet.

Comment: that wont install... every time I run now it asks if I want to build it.  when I click yes it asks over and over and over again.  I am using code::blocks.  clicking no opens a blank cmd like window with nothing in it.

Comment: I am also using code::blocks. Try to reinstall C::B(Code::blocks) then.

Comment: have you installed and un-installed monodevelop or something that rewrites DLL files?